# Making a struct visible to a main

Tags: c

I'm studying C and currently learning how to implement abstract data types using multiple files outside of one unified c file. I have a project that defines Clients and Stocks in separate header files where the behavior is defined in c files. In the end I'm going to be reading multiple files and filling multiple linked lists with Client and Stock info. However, I have a visibility problem in my main function where I attempt to call sizeof() on a Client struct.

The research I've done shows similar errors showing from not including the appropriate header files. I'm positive I'm including the proper header file, and I've also tried defining the struct in the header file instead of the c file.

I'm honestly not sure what it means by forward declaration of the struct, because I thought that it would "have all the info" about it when it includes the header file before my main. What steps can I take to resolve this issue?

Here is the error my compiler gives me when I try to compile my main:

```
main.c:32:31: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type
      'Client' (aka 'struct client')
        ListType clientList = create(sizeof(Client), compareClients);
                                     ^     ~~~~~~~~
./client.h:6:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct client'
typedef struct client Client;
               ^
1 error generated
```

My main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "client.h"
#include "stock.h"
#include "listADTgen.h"

/* Main function of the program. */
int  main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    if (argc > 5) { // Input validation on number of arguments.
        printf("Invalid format. Exiting...\n");
        return -1;
    }

    FILE *clientFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (clientFile == NULL) {   // Validate client file.
        printf("Error opening client file. Exiting...\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a list of all clients, read from the client file.
    int (*clientCompare) (Client *x, Client *y);
    clientCompare = compareClients;

    ListType clientList = create(sizeof(Client), compareClients);

    FILE *stockFile = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    if (stockFile == NULL) {    // Validate stock file.
        printf("Error opening stock file. Exiting...\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a list of all stocks, read from the stock file.

    FILE *stockClientFile = fopen(argv[3], "r");

    if (stockClientFile == NULL) {  // Validate stock_client file.
        printf("Error opening stock + client file. Exiting...\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Utilize previously built client and stock lists to put together the information
    // given to use by the stock_client file.

    printf("All good!\n");


    return 0;
}
```

client.h:

```
typedef struct client Client;

Client* createClient(int id, char *name, int phone, char *email);
void deleteClient(Client *c);
int getId(Client *c);
void setId(Client *c, int x);
char* getName(Client *c);
void setName(Client *c, char *pointer);
int getPhone(Client *c);
void setPhone(Client *c, int x);
char* getEmail(Client *c);
void setEmail(Client *c, char *pointer);
int compareClients(Client *x, Client *y);
```

client.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "client.h"

struct client {
    int id;
    char name[30];
    int phone;
    char email[30];

};

/* Creates and returns a pointer to a Client object. */
Client* createClient(int id, char *name, int phone, char *email) {
    Client *newClient = malloc(sizeof(Client));
    setId(newClient, id);
    setName(newClient, name);
    setPhone(newClient, phone);
    setEmail(newClient, email);

    return newClient;

}

/* Deletes a given Client by freeing the memory address allocated to them. */
void deleteClient(Client *c) {
    free(c);

}

/* Returns the id number of the given Client. */
int getId(Client *c) {
    return c->id;

}

 /* Sets the id to the given Client. */
void setId(Client *c, int x) {
    c->id = x;

}

/* Returns the name of a given Client. */
char* getName(Client *c) {
    char *p = c->name;
    return p;

}

/* Sets the name of the given Client. */
void setName(Client *c, char *pointer) {
    strcpy(c->name, pointer);

}

/* Returns the phone number of the given Client. */
int getPhone(Client *c) {
    return c->phone;

}

/* Sets the phone of the given Client. */
void setPhone(Client *c, int x) {
    c->phone = x;

}

/* Returns the email of a given Client. */
char* getEmail(Client *c) {
    char *p = c->email;
    return p;

}

/* Sets the email of the given Client. */
void setEmail(Client *c, char *pointer) {
    strcpy(c->email, pointer);

}

/* Compares two clients based on their id number. */
int compareClients(Client *x, Client *y) {
    int result = 0;
    if (x->id > y->id) {
        result = 1;
    } else if (x->id < y->id) {
        result = -1;
    }

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take the `sizeof` a structure, the compiler needs to have already "seen" a full definition of that structure. Since the structure is only defined in `client.c`, the compiler has no way of telling how large the structure is while compiling `main.c`.

In this case, though, I think your problem is that you are allocating your list (`clientList`) using the wrong type. The list needs to contain pointers to `Client` objects (`Client *`), not actual `Client` objects; its elements will have size `sizeof(Client *)`, not `sizeof(Client)`.

Comment: Yes sir! This was it. Literally one asterisk away from mostly working...
Thank you for your help. C is entirely unforgiving and challenging : )